# group a column of dataframe based on another column of maximum k size?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-handling

I have a movie rating/watched`enter code here` dataset with columns userid, movieId and timestamp.

I want to groupby the dataframe according to the users and each row should contain the movies not more than a certain time (lets say 500 in my case ) but no of items at each entry should not be greater than 100.

```
input_data={'userId':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1,1],'movieId':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],'timestamp':[100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000]}

input_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['userId','movieId','timestamp'],data=input_data)
input_df
```

[image]

The Output should look like:

```
output_data={'userId':[1,2,3,1],'movies':[[10,20,30],[40,50],[60,70,80],[90,100]]}
output_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['userId','movies'],data=output_data)
output_df
```

[image]

Comment: Your output is not considering an 'end time' correct? Also do you want userId 1 twice in the output?

Comment: `Input` is a reserved keyword...Don't use as a `var` name

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by ..."but no of items at each entry should not be greater than 100" ??  And also in your output, it does not seem that you are taking into account your specification that ..."each row should contain the movies not more than a certain time (lets say 500 in my case )"

Comment: End time is not considered.

Comment: And, maximum entry should be 100 means.. if We have any row having more than 100 items , then the row should be splitted into multiple rows but with same userId .. if you have 500 items ,, it will be splitted into 5 rows of 100 items each with same userId

Comment: if you have any difficulty with limit of items in each entry.. you can ignore for a while,,